ReactPlayer is re-rendering when using custom buttons
I am using ReactPlayer to play videos from different sources like Youtube and Vimeo.
I want to implement a custom play/pause button along with a custom Slider to show player progress.
I am currently using React.useState to track play/pause status and player progress, however, whenever I click on the play/pause button, the Player is re-rendering, making it load again and start from beginning.
Is there any other way to do it and prevent player from re-rendering?
Here's the player code
<ReactPlayer ref={playerRef} url={source.url} controls={true} width='100%' height={smallScreen ? '420px' : '100%'} playing={playing} onProgress={player.progress} />

<Button startIcon={playing ? <PauseRounded /> : <PlayArrowRounded />} onClick={player.togglePlay}>{smallScreen ? '' : playing ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</Button>

<Slider size='small' min={0} max={100} value={playerProgress} color='inherit' sx={{ ml: 1, mr: 2 }} />


Here's the player controls code
const [playing, setPlaying] = React.useState(false);

const [playerProgress, setPlayerProgress] = React.useState(0);

const player = {
    togglePlay: React.useMemo(() => () => {
        setPlaying(!playing);
    }, [playing]),
    progress: (state) => {
        // console.log(playerRef.current);
        setPlayerProgress(state.played * 100);
    },
};

Thank you.
I've tried using Native React Components, but it seems complicated as I am using Meteor Framework and have a few subscriptions that I need to make which I am unable to figure out how to use with Native React.

The issue is the states. Your buttons and player are in the same functional component. So when the button change the state, the functional component is asking everything to "react". So solve this, one easy way will be separate the player and buttons in different components. then use zustand or redux kind of state management to control the player
